# Are tensorflow2 keras models compatible with the Edge TPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, google-coral

I am trying to convert the keras model located here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant to a model that can run on the Edge TPU. What this example fails to mention is that in order to compile the model to something that is runnable on the TPU it needs to get saved first as a "frozen model" to a .pb file. I tried doing that but the Edge tpu compiler still complains that the model's tensor size's are still not constant. I also read somewhere that tensorflow2 does not support frozen graphs yet. Is that true, and if so, how can I convert this keras model to something that is runnable on the TPU? Does a complete guide for how to write a TPU compatible model exist somewhere?

Comment: Have you gone through the TPU model compatibility documentation at https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/ ?

Comment: Yes I have, and I am following the procedure to convert my model, but everything I have done so far has failed. And the problem is that the compiler complains about non static sized tensors ,even if I save the model as .pb first. Am I missing something else that should be obvious?

Comment: Tensor sizes cannot be dynamic like (None, None,3). It must be a fixed constant like (128,128,3). Can you check if all the Tensors are written as per above statement?